# How to run an application on multiple computers in an LAN

Tags: bash, macos, shell, networking

It may be a simple question, I humbly apologize for that.
I looking for a way to simultaneously launch an application in all the computers in local area network.

I'm studying networking and have setup a small lan at my place. For this particular question, I have to launch an application in each of the computers in my network. I have been wondering if there is an automated way of launching the application in all the computers if I launch it from any of the computers in the network.

For example, Let C1, C2, C3 be the computers in my network. Let A be the application I want to launch. When I launch A in C1, it has to be launched simultaneously in C2 and C3 as well;

I wonder if there are some scripts or something of that sort for the purpose. Could you help me?

I'm using MAC and mostly enter use scp when I want to deploy applications across my network.

Comment: Maybe you need to use sockets and check for background process...if computer C1 launch 'x' app, then the app running in the background check that the process has started and is running, and send a signal to all the other machines....the machines received the signal with the app name, checks if the app exist in the computer and then launch the app....what do you think?

Comment: Hmm... seems like an idea. I was thinking of that... but then found that Hadoop uses a much simpler approach to spawn its datanodes using ssh... I guess...! I haven't found the answer yet but trying on those lines trying some bash scripts...!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. There is already a nice little tool for the purpose - DSH. There are some issues I noticed. For example, even though the path to an executable is added to the .profile file, it won't pick it up. Instead one has to give the absolute path. However, for now, it solves my problem.

I'll see, if I can contribute towards making it better...!